# Definition of Roelcke uniformity

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $(G,\mathcal T)$ be a topological group. The set of all uniformities on $G$ forms a lattice $\frak A$ and the set of all uniformities on $G$ producing $\cal T$, forms a lattice $\frak B$.

The meet of the left and right uniformities of $\cal T$ is called the **Roelcke uniformity** of $\cal T$. But where is the meet calculated, in $\frak A$ or in $\frak B$?

Answer (score 2):

[image]
[image]

(cited from Alexander V. Arhangel'skii, Mikhail G. Tkachenko, "Topological groups and related structures", Atlantis Press, Paris; World Sci. Publ., NJ, 2008).

Comment: probably *compatible with* $G$ means that it produces the same topology as the original topology of $G$. And it seems the theorem says that it does not matter whether you take $\frak A$ or $\frak B$.

Comment: So I guess $\frak B$ is a sublattice of $\frak A$.

Comment: Can you confirm these comments?